# Expect script does continue after putting a value

Tags: scripting, expect, suse, zypper

I wrote the following expect script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout 10
spawn zypper in --no-recommends pdns
expect {
  -re {^.* Solution (\d): (?:break pdns)} {
    set solution "$expect_out(1,string)"
    exp_continue
  }
  "Choose from above solutions by number or cancel" {
   puts "$solution"
   send "\r"
  }
}
```

The program puts my `$solution` correctly (in the example below, "3" is correctly placed), however then aborts execution, seemingly sending the carriage return, but not in a way that would make the zypper command I am spawning continue:

```
suse-test-647578bd8-95qsc:/ # ./install-pdns.expect 
spawn zypper in --no-recommends pdns
Refreshing service 'container-suseconnect-zypp'.
Problem retrieving the repository index file for service 'container-suseconnect-zypp':
[container-suseconnect-zypp|file:/usr/lib/zypp/plugins/services/container-suseconnect-zypp] 
Warning: Skipping service 'container-suseconnect-zypp' because of the above error.
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
Resolving package dependencies...

Problem: the to be installed pdns-4.6.2-lp154.186.32.x86_64 requires 'systemd', but this requirement cannot be provided
  not installable providers: systemd-249.11-150400.6.8.x86_64[SLE_BCI]
 Solution 1: Following actions will be done:
  remove lock to allow installation of systemd-249.11-150400.6.8.x86_64[SLE_BCI]
  remove lock to allow installation of systemd-default-settings-branding-SLE-0.7-3.2.1.noarch[SLE_BCI]
  remove lock to allow installation of systemd-presets-branding-SLE-15.1-20.8.1.noarch[SLE_BCI]
  remove lock to allow installation of systemd-default-settings-0.7-3.2.1.noarch[SLE_BCI]
  remove lock to allow installation of systemd-presets-common-SUSE-15-150100.8.12.1.noarch[SLE_BCI]
 Solution 2: do not install pdns-4.6.2-lp154.186.32.x86_64
 Solution 3: break pdns-4.6.2-lp154.186.32.x86_64 by ignoring some of its dependencies

Choose from above solutions by number or cancel [1/2/3/c/d/?] (c): 3

suse-test-647578bd8-95qsc:/ #
```

I attempted combining the separate `puts` and `send` to `puts "$solution\r"`, but it would abort without putting the value.

I attempted to add

```
eof { exp_continue }
"Installing:" { exp_continue }
eof {}
```

to the `expect` block, and additionally tried to expect `eof` outside of the existing `expect` block. Neither seem to make the `zypper` command continue.

To clarify: on a manual execution, `zypper` expects "3" and then "enter" and then proceeds to install the package (hence the attempt with expecting "Installing:" afterwards).

I would appreciate any suggestions on what else to try!

Thanks for reading!

Comment: `puts` does not write to the spawned process. Use `send "$solution\r"` to do so.

Comment: Hi, putting `send "$solution\r"` does not put the value and does not continue execution either.

Comment: Thank you, combining your suggestion with `exp_continue` worked - full script in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Solved using a combination of @meuth's suggestion and `exp_continue`:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout 10
spawn zypper in --no-recommends pdns
expect {
  -re {^.* Solution (\d): (?:break pdns)} {
    set solution "$expect_out(1,string)"
    exp_continue
  }
  "Choose from above solutions by number or cancel" {
   send "$solution\r"
   exp_continue
  }
  eof {}
}
```